# Avoiding Nested Subscriptions and Passing Values to Error Handler

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is it possible to change the property of an emitted value from a Subject before passing it to another Observable? For example:

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.myService.mySubject.subscribe(value => {
    value.property = true;
    this.subscriptions.push(this.myOtherService.myMethod(value.propertyTwo).subscribe(value => {
    // do things with value
    });
}, (error) => {
    // how can I still access said value in the error handler?
});
```

I push my subscriptions to a private subscriptions array so that I can unsubscribe from them in my `ngOnDestroy`. I'd like to get to get rid of the nested subscription in this case and was wondering if it was possible to do so?

Also, how can I still access the `value` variable in the error handler of my subscription?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chain them up with `switchMap` and handle error with `catch`. In well written observable chains usually you don't need many subscriptions

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.myService.mySubject.switchMap(value => {
value.property = true;
return this.myOtherService.myMethod(value.propertyTwo)})
.catch(e=>Observable.of(e)).subscribe())
```